# Apache Server - Wrong Certificate

Tags: apache, security-certificate

At work we are moving a website from "outside" to "inside". Standard LAMP website (Apache, MySQL, PHP).

The issue I'm having is that it's serving up the wrong certificate.

https:/intranet - on my computer, and some other computers, it's serving up the SSL for intranet like it should...

On other computers it's serving up the certificate for https:/intranettest instead. HTTPS:/intranet/ put in browser, yet Apache is serving the wrong certificate.

I'm at a loss for "how" it's serving the wrong certificate for some websites, and not others (more wrong than right)... If it hits the server, the DNS switch has occured like it should, so they are arriving at the "New" server instead of the "old".

I hope I'm asking this right.

Answer (score 1):

After much gnashing of teeth... the issue was that Apache SSL Virtual Hosts apparently don't like *:443, when dealing with multiple hosts.

We have an internal IP for the server... and an external IP for the server. To fix the issue, I created two virtual hosts - explicitly declaring the IP-Address.

Changed From...

```
<VirtualHost *:443>...</VirtualHost>
```

To

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.1:443>...</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 200.58.1.1:443>...</VirtualHost>
```